# Not able to map JSON to classes in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cassandra

I have a cassandra db which returns data in JSON format say -

```
{
    "name": "Parag"
    "city": "Bangalore"
    "state": "Karnataka"
}
```

Can I map above configuration in following kind of classes :

**class 1 :** `Address.java` and it contains city and state.

**class 2 :** `Person.java` and it contains name and Address's object

I tried to use `@embedded` and `@embeddable` but it is still not mapping fields for address.

It's just an example. Actual code I can't paste here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bean class. Set the values returned from database using setters and get values where it is required using getters.